# document.getElementById não encontra elemento manualmente inserido no DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Olá, eu estou uma dificuldade em obter um elemento através do id de uma Classe com `document.getElementById(id)` do `DOM` usando `Javascript`

e tenho um estilo de painel em `css`

```
#painel {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Objetos que podem ser colocados nas páginas HTML (implementa todos os aspetos do DOM).

```
function Visualizavel(etiqueta, id) {
    if (etiqueta) {
        //aqui funciona perfeitamente, criando a tag table
        this.visualizacao = document.createElement(etiqueta);
    }
    if (id) {
        //pretendo obter "div.id=painel", mas não chega aqui
        this.apresentar(document.getElementById(id));
    }
}
```

função para Colocar a visualização no elemento HTML da página

```
Visualizavel.prototype.apresentar = function (elemento) {
    //Elimina, eventuais, filhos do elemento HTML da página
    while (elemento.hasChildNodes()) {
        elemento.removeChild(elemento.lastChild);
    }
    //Coloca a visualização no elemento HTML da página
    if (this.visualizacao) {
        elemento.appendChild(this.visualizacao);
    }
};
```

classe Painel `tag table` e um `id painel`

```
function Painel(id) {
  //filho da classe visualizavel
  Visualizavel.call(this, "table", id);
  //id = painel
  this.id = id;
  //criar a tabela
  var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  var tr, td; 
  //linhas
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    //colunas
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      td = document.createElement("td");
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  this.visualizacao.appendChild(tbody);

  //função para carregar pagina do painel
  this.carregarPainel = function() {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    //mesmo que <div id="painel">Painel</div> em html
    div.id = this.id;
   //mesmo que <body><div id="painel">Painel</div><body> em html
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  };
}
Painel.prototype = Object.create(Visualizavel.prototype);
Painel.prototype.constructor = Painel;
```

a minha dúvida é que quando crio uma instancia de novo painel

```
var painel = new Painel(painel);
alert("ID: "+painel.id); // irá mostrar "ID: painel"
```

e como sendo extendida da `classe Visualizavel`, somente verifica o `id` ate o uso de `if` e não chega a `Visualizavel.prototype.apresentar` a `tabela` porque o `id` não foi encontrado

```
if (id) {
   alert("Mesmo ID: " + id); // irá mostrar "Mesmo ID: painel"
   //não chega aqui 
   this.apresentar(document.getElementById(id));
   //porque não reconhece 
   // nenhum element com id=painel mas,
   // tenho div.id=this.id, dentro da body
   //em carregar pagina painel
 }
```

e depois quando pretendo, chamar o carregar Painel,

```
painel.carregarPainel();
```

não aparece nada